# Draw Basemap above xarray plot

Tags: python, python-xarray, matplotlib-basemap

I have a xarray dataset `clip_ds` and have visualised the data array using `plot`. Now, I want to add a country boundary using Basemap's `drawcountries()`. Apparently, there is something wrong with the extent I am using in basemap (I guess), but both the country border and the data plot won't show up together. I have tried interchanging the position of `clip_ds.pr[0].plot()` before and after I create basemap, and it gives me two different results as shown below:

1. [Xarray PLOT BEFORE BASEMAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og56t.png) (Note that the colorbar from xarray plot is still there)
2. [Xarray PLOT AFTER BASEMAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypvK1.png) (Notice difference from 3, height of the plot shrinks here and the tick labels disappears, probably overlapped by basemap.)
3. [Xarray plot only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTB7w.png)

Loading seperate shapefile using `map.readshapefile` also gives same kind of problem. I know there might be a way around this using `cartopy`, but I like the Basemap functionalities and would like to know if there is any solution to this.

```
map=Basemap(projection='merc',     
               resolution='l',
               llcrnrlon=clip_ds.lon[0],
               llcrnrlat=clip_ds.lat[0],
               urcrnrlon=clip_ds.lon[-1],
               urcrnrlat=clip_ds.lat[-1])
map.drawcountries()
clip_ds.pr[0].plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This might be a good GH issue to be added into https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues